# Remote finish an activity called by intent-filter?

Tags: android, android-intent, activity-lifecycle

I have 2 activities: **A** and **B**. A calls browser intent via `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` and after user logins in browser he's redirected by intent-filter to activity B.
The problem is: **When user gets to B, activity A must finish.**
I know about `startActivityForResult()`, but I do not directly call A->B, it goes A->browser->B, so it doesn't work. 
I can't use onStop() and onDestroy() methods in A however, because app would crash on orientation change.
What shall I do?

Comment: Is it an option to use `WebView` instead of full-fledged browser?

Answer (score 0):

> When user gets to B, activity A must finish.

Why ?

Close it, if user comes back from B ( or browser )

I never had the problem, that a activity must finish. Maybe you can explain the situation a little bit more, so we can understand better.

BTW: you can also lock the orientation programmatically, but I am thinking you are running in the wrong direction.

// hans

Comment: A is Login Activity with one button "Login". When pressed, he's redirected to browser, where logins and returns to app (It's API restriction). When user presses "back" on Activity B, he must exit the app, no return to login activity A

Answer (score 0):

For `Android API Version from 16` Use `finishAffinity` to close the `Activity B` as well as all activities immediately below it, so that the Activity A will also be displayed.

Just `Override` the `finish` method in `Activity B`

```
 @Override
public void finish(){
    finishAffinity(); // supported only from API 16
}
```

By default all the Activity will have same `taskAffinity` as the package name. If you want to close only specific `Activities` , then set a custom `Affinity` name for the required `Activities`

**finishAffinity** - *Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in the current task that have the same affinity.  This is typically used when an application can be launched on to another task (such as from an ACTION_VIEW of a content type it understands) and the user has used the up navigation to switch out of the current task and in to its own task.*